# JQuery Ajax Returning Blank Page but manual xmlhttprequest works fine

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I tried a jquery get on a particular page on my forums

```
$.get("/members/",
function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

but it would always return a blank page. However, if I use an xmlhttprequest object with my own code, it grabs the html page just fine:

```
xhr({method: "GET", url: "/members/",
onload: function(responseDetails) {
if (responseDetails.status == 200) {
alert(responseDetails.responseText);
}}});
```

Intestingly, I used the jquery get on another page and it worked fine:

```
$.get("/stats/",
function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

In any case, could anyone explain what's going on and how I can fix this? I'd rather not have this long stupid section of code for my custom xhr method:

```
function xhr(details) {
try {var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();} catch (e) {
var XMLHTTP_IDS = new Array('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0','MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0', 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0', 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' );
var success = false;
for (var i=0;i < XMLHTTP_IDS.length && !success; i++) {
    try {
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(XMLHTTP_IDS[i]);
    success = true;
        } catch (e) {}
}
if (!success) throw new Error('Unable to create XMLHttpRequest.');
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
var responseState = {
            responseText:(xmlhttp.readyState==4 ? xmlhttp.responseText : ''),
            readyState:xmlhttp.readyState,
            status:(xmlhttp.readyState==4 ? xmlhttp.status : 0)
        }
        if (details["onreadystatechange"]) {
            details["onreadystatechange"](responseState);
        }
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            if (details["onload"] && xmlhttp.status>=200 && xmlhttp.status<300) {
                details["onload"](responseState);
            }
            if (details["onerror"] && (xmlhttp.status<200 || xmlhttp.status>=300)) {
                details["onerror"](responseState);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
      xmlhttp.open(details.method, details.url);
    } catch(e) {
      if( details["onerror"] ) {
        details["onerror"]({responseXML:'',responseText:'',readyState:4,responseHeaders:'',status:403,statusText:'Forbidden'});
      }
      return;
    }
    if (details.headers) {
        for (var prop in details.headers) {
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(prop, details.headers[prop]);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send((typeof(details.data)!='undefined')?details.data:null);
}
```

Thanks! (Hopefully it's not a problem with how that forum page was set up, since it's a hosted forums, not my own.)

EDIT: response headers on xhr call

```
Date    Sat, 30 Apr 2011 01:21:54 GMT
Server  Apache
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Expires Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Encoding    gzip
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Length  7723
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

response headers on failed jquery get call

```
Date    Sat, 30 Apr 2011 01:23:38 GMT
Server  Apache
Content-Encoding    gzip
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Length  26
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: can you add your server side code of /members ? It has to do with the way you are sending data from the server. jQuery is fine.

Comment: I don't have access to the server side code for /members since it's a hosted forums (zetaboards)...

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Firebug/similar? Do you see any errors? What's the content-type of the response?

Comment: yes i tried with firebug. i added the content-types of the responses for both the xhr and the jquery get to the post.

Comment: Thank you no.good.at.coding for talking about firebug!

I looked into the REQUEST headers and saw in firebug that the xhr code was not sending a "X-Requested-With" while the jquery version did.

I'm guessing for some reason they block all requests with that "X-Requested-With" header, so I modified the ajax call to remove that header and it works!

Thank you again, no.good.at.coding!

Comment: @spiLa Good to know! You might consider posting this as the answer yourself and marking it as the solution (I realize that sometimes new users have to wait a while to perform certain actions so you might come back to it later)